# What is the objective in the new Unreal Tournament Blitz gamemode?

Tags: unreal-tournament-4

What is the objective in the new UT Blitz gamemode and how it needs to be played?

Comment: This doesn't seem to really be much of a problem.

Comment: I find it as a problem because it's something unknown for lots of players and I believe there are people who will be find the answer helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who don't know, **Blitz**, formerly known as Flag Run, is the new Unreal Tournament gamemode, by default played 5 versus 5 on new, specially designed maps. A Blitz match consists of 6 rounds of which each team attacks 3 times and defends 3 times.

**Attacking team's** main objective is to deliver the flag to the opponents base capture spot in the timelimit. The quicker attacking team manages to deliver the flag, the better the result will be for them. Other way to win the round is to annihilate the defending team (players on defense have only 5 lives while attacking players have unlimited lives). In order to attack efficiently, flag carrier uses Rally on marked spots to give teammates ability to teleport to that location.

**Defending team's** only objective is to stop enemy to deliver their flag to defenders base in the timelimit. The trick is the defending players can't be as aggressive as attackers because of the limited lives. Also, many times I witnessed cap in 15 seconds because defenders didn't focus on the enemy flag carrier, so keep an eye on him!

At the end of the match, **the winning team is one with fastest total capture time**.

There is also a short [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrvrrpH3Vzs).

EDIT: Additional info about Blitz:

Game start: 
Whoever picks up flag is highlighted to defenders for about 3 secs.

Throughout round: 
Flag carrier remains invisible to all defenders until carrier comes into any defefender's field of view; while the carrier is in ANY defender's field of view, carrier is visible to all defenders, and game automatically announces carrier's location  (while they have not moved to another) to defenders (as long as they were spotted by any defender).

Flag drops: 
Flag location visibile to all

Carrier entering defender base: 
Game automatically announces to all, regardless fo whether carrier was spotted or not; but only one announcement per entry. 
Flag must completely leave area defined as "base" for game to announce re-entry. This is why a lot of people complain about "no announcement/warning" when on a map such as Meltdown, the flag  leaves defender base main floor, and maybe backs out to core, but never goes all the way back up the ramp, then re enters. They get caught with their pants down dick out, cuz none of their teammates spotted the carrier coming back up, and so the carrier never gets highlighted, along with a location update